# Is a small breaking change enough to do a Major Version Upgrade while using SemVer?

Tags: version-control, versioning, semantic-versioning

I am new to the concept of SemVer. It's seems like very promising idea to implement in my current project.

According to the SemVer concept, if a project is name `project-a.b.c` then, a is Major update(breaking changes), b is Minor update(newer implementations), c is patch update(bug fixes).

My question is, say if I had a Very Small breaking change for which I need to build and update my repo. What should I do then?

> Is it a Major update or a Patch update?

Also, is SemVer only suitable for certain software technologies and not for every thing? For example, some Node Devs told me they rarely use this. But, I am not sure what percentage of people are practising it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking change is a breaking change, no *if*s or *but*s. You should do a MAJOR update.

SemVer purpose is to `convey meaning about the underlying code and what has been modified from one version to the next`. This scheme is suitable for everything where there is a need to solve compatibility issues of any kind and SemVer convention fits the purpose.

https://semver.org/

It is useful to ask a number of questions to help you determine the impact and not to deviate from the SemVer convention:

1. Have there been a change to my deliverable?
2. Can this change break anyone's code out there?
   Yes => breaking change; No => move on to next question of MINOR vs PATCH.

As to whether developers using or not using SemVer convention you would be surprised to find huge number of projects using it because of its usefulness and simplicity, so I would encourage you to use it where it makes sense, e.g. distributed deliverable.

Answer (score 1):

Having to increment the major version may feel heavy-handed for *small* breaking changes (I'm unsure if this is a rational concern).

There may be a strong temptation to use [deprecation releases](https://semver.org/#how-should-i-handle-deprecating-functionality) to subvert the requirement and release a breaking change on a minor increment, given 'sufficient' notice. But that would violate the [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0 specification](https://semver.org/#spec-item-8):

> Major version X (X.y.z | X > 0) MUST be incremented if any backward incompatible changes are introduced to the public API. It MAY also include minor and patch level changes. Patch and minor versions MUST be reset to 0 when major version is incremented.

Major version upgrades don't have to be onerous if the deprecation steps are followed "*so that users can smoothly transition to the new API*".

> **How should I handle deprecating functionality?**
>
> Deprecating existing functionality is a normal part of software development and is often required to make forward progress. When you deprecate part of your public API, you should do two things: (1) update your documentation to let users know about the change, (2) issue a new minor release with the deprecation in place. Before you completely remove the functionality in a new major release there should be at least one minor release that contains the deprecation so that users can smoothly transition to the new API.

---

To minimize ambiguity, the spec relies on a [formal definition of the word 'MUST'](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119#section-1):

> 1. MUST   This word, or the terms "REQUIRED" or "SHALL", mean that the
>    definition is an absolute requirement of the specification.

Comment: I think the major problem introduced by major version changes is maintenance -- how many major versions are you willing to simultaneously support. This is a very practical reason to avoid introducing major updates. The solution is probably to methodically design and batch your breaking changes. This requires long-term strategic thinking.

Comment: It's also a benefit that there is friction to add even small breaking changes. It makes you think if it's actually worth implementing the change, or if it's possible to make it in a compatible way.